# How do I include Scintilla in an XCode 3.2.5 project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode3.2, scintilla

I downloaded Scintilla, built and ran `ScintillaTest`. That worked (almost) fine. Now, I want to include Scintilla in a new project, but can't seem to figure out how to. I tried ctrl-clicking my target and selecting `Add Existing Framework...`, then `Add Other...` and finally file located at `scite337/scintilla/cocoa/ScintillaFramework/build/Release/Scintilla.framework` (obviously I omitted the first part of the path).

After I did this I just added an `#import` statement in the AppDelegate of my further untouched new project. Upon hitting Cmd+R it says `ScintillaView.h: no such file or directory`...
I thought that if I added the framework to my only target it would pass the location of the header files to the compiler (and preprocessor). Obviously it doesn't, so I assume I'll have to add the paths of the header files (and maybe other files) to the Build Settings, but there are lots of Build Settings, so I don't have a clue where.

If you don't have access to XCode 3.2.x, please leave how you'd do it in a newer version. I've found a lot of information on other XCode matters for higher versions did that work well in XCode 3.2.5 too (with a little bit of searching for menu items and settings panels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the ScintillaTest XCode project I discovered how it works: you have to import the *XCode project* called ScintillaFramework, which is the file named `ScintillaFramework.xcodeproj` (obviously). But that isn't enough, after that XCode still can't find the header files in the framework. I looked at the build settings in the ScintillaTest project and found 'Header Search Paths' set to `../../`. Setting this failed in my project, it had to be one directory less back: `../`.  No I just need to get the compiler to accept the C++ constructs in the Scintilla framework.

**Update:**
Strangely, this stopped working. I do not understand it either. So I just right-clicked my target, from there: add existing framework...->add other...->[browse to `ScintillaFramework/build/Release/Scintilla.framework`]. This works partially, see my newest question.